# Return the Table whose primary key is another table's foreign key, SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I can return the name of the table of which a foreign key references, but I want to do the opposite.

Suppose I have two tables, Users and Address, and Address has a foreign key to Users (one-to-many). I also made this bidirectional so that I can get the User from the address table.

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    address = relationship("Address", back_populates="user")


class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'address'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    company_name = Column(String)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = relationship("User", back_populates="address")
```

If I wanted to figure out the name of the parent table, in a way that works for any other table in a similar relationship, I can to this:

```
for i in Address.__table__.foreign_key_constraints:
   print(i.referred_table)

tab = Table(Address.__tablename__, Base.metadata, autoload_with=engine, extend_existing=True)

for i in tab.foreign_key_constraints:
      print(i.referred_table)
#both output "user" which is the __tablename__ of User
```

This was me accessing the User table using the foreign key constraint attribute. But how do I do the opposite, using an attribute from User to access Address? I mainly want to know so I can handle relationships in a bulk core insert.

```
tab = Table(User.__tablename__, Base.metadata, autoload_with=engine, extend_existing=True)

records = df.to_dict(orient="records")
insert_stmt = sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.insert(tab).values(records)
#list of primary keys
pks = [pk.name for pk in tab.primary_key]
update_columns = {col.name: col for col in insert_stmt.excluded if col.name not in pks}
update_statement = insert_stmt.on_conflict_do_update(index_elements=pks, set_=update_columns)
```

The above works once I execute the on_conflict_do_update statement, but it does not generate any Address rows.

Comment: You want all tables that refer to a given table's key?

Comment: @Shawn Sort of. I want all tables that have my table's primary key as a foreign key. In my case it would just be one. Specifically, it would be akin to returning the address table utilizing some attribute/method from my user table. Currently, I only know how to return the user table as an attribute of the address table

Answer (score 0):

I found one way of doing it, but it's not as clean as I wanted.

```
tab = list(inspect(User).relationships)[0].entity.local_table
```

For any declarative table (classes), you can inspect them to get a Mapper Object. The Mapper Object has relationships as an attribute, which returns a collection of relationships.

```
inspect(User).relationships
#Get the relationship, note this will return the relationship attribute from the class
list(inspect(User).relationships)[0]
```

So I then get the mapper/class this relationship belongs to with .entity. Then from the declarative table, a table object is returned with the local_table attribute

```
entity = list(inspect(User).relationships)[0].entity
tab = entity.local_table
```

This statement should evaluate to True

```
tab == Address.__table__
```